# How to Access my SQLite Database Values through Mobile Browsers using PHP?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new to Android Development and I have an doubt regarding SQLite Database.
I know Android is a Mobile OS and SQLite is inbuild database for Android.
And I know How to access the SQLite Database using java and other things(like Syc with SQLite and MySQL).
My question is if I have a App and stored the value in SQLite Database, If there is any possible ways to access that
values using android Mobile Browsers? It may be I'm using PHP with get the data from SQLite?
is it possile or any Security issues will be there(to viloating the Rules)?

Comment: check out this library https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Android-Debug-Database . This might be help ful

Comment: There can be ways, For example you can keep a copy of db in external storage and use it from browser whenever the given API is accessed. But this will raise security issues. I won't recommend doing it. For debugging purpose it is fine, but not for production.

Comment: Thanks for Link but i need without using library . @Redman

Comment: i tried  and get the data from external storage but android does not allowed me . .@TheLittleNaruto

Comment: @Moorthy just try to understand what he is doing inside library

Comment: Check this out: https://viljamis.com/2012/file-upload-support-on-mobile/

Comment: @Redman Yes, i read the doc from give URL by you. Its look like a DashBoard
but i need to accesss via PHP program language because each time i cant open the dashboard and check the values
so i need to check via programs

Answer (score 0):

try using `JavaScriptInterface` in android app and in PHP side get the data from JavaScript 
like this

```
public class JavaScriptInterface {
            Context mContext;

            JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
                mContext = c;
            }
            @JavascriptInterface
            public int getconsentid() {
                return consentid;
            }
            @JavascriptInterface
            public int getrequestno() {
                return requestno;
            }
                @JavascriptInterface
            public String getAllergyName() {

                String AllergyNames = "";
                SQLiteDatabase db = new DatabaseHelper(InmateAssessment.this).getWritableDatabase();
                String query = "select AllergyName from lstAllergy order by AllergyName";
                Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
                for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    AllergyNames += cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("AllergyName")) + "|";
                }
                AllergyNames = AllergyNames.substring(0, AllergyNames.length() - 1);
                cursor.close();
                db.close();
            return AllergyNames;
        }
```

and in webpage side use Javascript to get these methods

```
#boxes .window {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 450px;
    height: 450px;
    display: none;
    z-index: 9999;
    background-color: #c9d9f6;
}

    var pid = window.jsondata.getpid();
    var sid = window.jsondata.getsid();
    var userid = window.jsondata.getuid();
    var flag = window.jsondata.getisserch();
    var formscreenid = window.jsondata.getscreenid();
```

Comment: The post is related to Access data in Web browsers not inside the app/webview